# Eigenvalues of complement of regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

So I have encountered the following fact:

Let $G$ be a $d$-regular graph with adjacency eigenvalues $\lambda_1\geq...\geq\lambda_n$. Then its complement graph $\bar{G}$ has eigenvalues $n-1-\lambda_1,-(\lambda_2+1),...,-(\lambda_n+1)$.

The proof uses the fact that $A(\bar{G})=J-A(G)-I$, where $J$ is the matrix with all ones. So if $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda_i$, then $A(\bar{G})v_i=Jv_i-A(G)v_i-v_i$. If $i=1$, then since $G$ is regular, $v_1$ must be the vector of all ones, hence $Jv_1=nv_1$.

But for $i>1$, then does the equation $A(\bar{G})v_i=Jv_i-A(G)v_i-v_i=Jv_i-\lambda_iv_i-v_i=-(\lambda_i+1)v_i$ imply that $Jv_i=0$? If it does, then I can't see why it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $Jv_i=0$ for all $i>1$. This is because, the matrix of $1$s has only one nonzero eigenvalue, $n$. Thus, since we have already covered its eigenvalue in $v_1$, and since a symmetric matrix has all independent eigenvectors, which are orthogonal to each other, therefore the vectors $v_i$ for $i>1$ are in the null space of $A(\overline{G})$, whence $Jv_i=0$.

Comment: By independent I assume you mean orthogonal right?

Comment: @paulinho not necessary. It means that we cannot express one vector as a linear combination of the others. Though orthogonal vectors are independent, but independent vectors need not be orthogonal

Comment: Right, but if the eigenvectors of $A(G)$ weren’t orthogonal, then just being linearly independent wouldn’t be enough to conclude that every other eigenvectors of $A(G)$ is in the null space of $J$. To be precise, the column space of $J$, which is spanned by one vector (also an eigenvector of $A(G)$, is orthogonal to the null space of $J$. The rest of $A$’s eigenvectors are orthogonal to the column space of $J$ (because they are orthogonal to the vector that spans it), and hence they must be in the null space of $J$.

Comment: @paulinho thanks! edited the post

Comment: Oh I see how it works. Thanks vidyarthi and @paulinho